# Numeric attributes of SVG tag in HTML5 as math expressions like <circle cx="10+50" cy="20+50" r="40"/>

Tags: html, math, svg

Is there a way to have numeric attributes of SVG tag in HTML5 as simple math expressions like the mathematical expressions for coordinates of center of circle in the following HTML5 code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="10+50" cy="20+50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not valid SVG, according to the [SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#DataTypeLength). So the answer is no.

Comment: @mikeyq6 That's strange for such a simple thing

Comment: Depending on where the source is coming from, one approach could be to create a shift transformation to move the origin to (50,50), and then put your circle at (10,20).  But then the real question is what's making this svg tag, and why can't it do the math?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read in the [Attribute Index](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/attindex.html) of the SVG Specification that the acceptable values for `cx` and `cy` are Coordinates. Following the hyperlink in that document, you can read that coordinates are `lengths`:

> <length>: A length is a distance measurement. The format of a <length>
>   is a <number> optionally followed immediately by a unit identifier.

This means that what you want to do is not supported by svg.

You may want to use javascript to dynamically compute your coordinates and set them inside the svg.

Some libraries make it easier to manipulate svg  in javascript, one of them is [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/).